# How to fill in a shape using force-directed layout in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I am using the TikZ force directed graph library, and would like to draw a filled-in triangle between three graph nodes.  I would have thought this would do it, but it only draws the triangle boundary without any fill:

```
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing} \usegdlibrary{trees} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph [tree layout, nodes={draw}]
  { a -- b,
    b -- c,
    c -- a,
    c -- d};
  \path[red,draw,fill=green] (a) -- (b) -- (d) -- (a); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542283/47927

Answer (score 3):

Using the node names without specifying a specific coordinate doesn't give you a closed path, so `fill` doesn't work. You can use

```
\path[red, draw, fill=green] (a.center) -- (b.center) -- (d.center) -- (a.center);
```

[image]

But that's probably not what you want since the filled triangle will overlap the nodes. You could place the triangle `on background layer` using the `backgrounds` library, which also requires that you `fill` the nodes with `white` (or whatever the page color is).

[image]

Note that the red edge from `a` to `b` is on the background layer so is overdrawn by the black edge.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing, backgrounds} \usegdlibrary{trees} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph [tree layout, nodes={draw, fill=white}]
  { a -- b,
    b -- c,
    c -- a,
    c -- d};
  \scoped[on background layer]\path[red, draw, fill=green] (a.center) -- (b.center) -- (d.center) -- (a.center);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```